# How do Chrome and other HttpClients act when you choose to ignore SSL warnings?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

When visiting a website, if there is a self-signed certificate (or some other untrusted certificate) for example, when you choose to proceed anyway even after the warning, what happens?

Is the certificate temporarily used?
Is the traffic just sent without encryption?

Comment: Using browsers isn't a programming or development question, but is ontopic at security.SX where it is crossdupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213687/is-encryption-still-applied-if-you-ignore-the-ssl-certificate-warning and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110334/is-my-ssl-connection-encrypted-if-the-certificate-isnt-trusted . For libraries used by apps there is rarely a UI, but there is sometimes (an) option(s) specified in advance to ignore (some) cert errors, in which case the same answers apply.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks very much. Any idea on whether I should delete the question or just leave it?